# Show Modal View in Detail View in UISplitViewController in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to make a behavior like contacts app in iPhone. I'm expecting that a Modal shows in a Detail view when I click upper right add button. but now if I click upper right add button, the Modal shows in all screen. what method should I use? `showDetailViewController?` or presentViewController? I don’t know how to show Modal in only Detail View. please teach me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `presentModalViewController`

```
CustomModalViewController *modalVC =[[CustomModalViewController alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];
```

or with a UINavigationController

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you share any more info?

Comment: `presentModalViewController` has been deprecated since `iOS 6`; use this instead: `[self presentViewController: modalVC animated:YES completion:nil];`